# Setting a null value in an array

Tags: java, arrays

I am using object orientated programming and I have an array of objects with some indexes unfilled so `null`. But when I try to set one of the index with an object in it as `null`, it claims that it is `null` but still uses the fields and methods from the object that was there before.

I have tried using other indexes that are `null`. I just dont know what to do

```
Entity en = null;

for (int y = 0; y < NUM_ROWS; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < NUM_COLS; x++) {
      if (entities[y][x] == null) {
         en = new Entity(entities[y][x]);
         break;
      }
    }   
}       

entities[row][col] = en;
```

I have tried `entities[row][col] = null;`

I expect to be able to not have this index interfere with the rest of the program. All fields and methods should be inaccessible since it is null.

Comment: what if you change your condition`if (entities[y][x] == null) {` to `if (entities[y] != null && entities[y][x] != null) {`?

Comment: It's quite hard to understand what you want to do. When you go though the bi-dimensional array, if the value is null, are you trying to actually create a new `Entity`to replace the null value?

Comment: what are `row`and`col` in the last line?, Don't you think this line `en = new Entity(entities[y][x]);` is weird as `entities[y][x]` can only be `null` at this place?

Comment: You mention using fields and methods of the "old" object, but your example does not show any field or method access at all. There is not enough information here to diagnose anything. Providing a [complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would help.